# capturing desktop screen by mouse drag without using Robot Class?

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to grab and capture the current windows screen by mouse drag without using the method below?

`robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize); //Robot class`

When a web page height is too lengthy, the robot class will just capture the current screen, and I want to capture the entire web page, including if necessary by scrolling down the page.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat difficult one. What you can do is to get the coordinates of the mouse drag and pass them into new Rectangle

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture( 
   new Rectangle( myframe.getX(), myframe.getY(), 
                  myframe.getWidth(), myframe.getHeight() ) );
```

I hope this helps

Comment: again here, i have to use Jframe i think, is there is anyway to get direct control of windows screen or web page? i found some tools like snag-it it doing the same which i want it exactly?

Comment: Vignesh: Those tools take a screenshot and create a new full-screen window where they show that screenshot and you can interact with.

Comment: ya joey, but there we have two option., first one is your reply,.but we have one more option like grab the entire image or needed part.,in this option it wont capture the screen., we need to do manually... plz correct me if i am stand in wrong thought..